# Unit interval in $\mathbb{Q}$ is not totally bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I was reading an analysis textbook, and I came across with a theorem says that a set is compact iff it's closed and totally bounded.

But if we consider the unit interval in the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$, which is a famous example for a closed bounded non-compact set, isn't the set also totally bounded too? Since given any $\epsilon >0$, we can cover $[1,0]$ with intervals of length $2\epsilon$? Doesn't that then make the set compact?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ being closed means that $\mathbb{Q}$ contains all of its limit points. Is that true?

Comment: The problem with your argument is that $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is not closed.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify a bit more? Isn't the complement of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]=\mathbb{Q} \setminus [0,1]$ open in $\mathbb{Q}$? Because for any $q>1$, I can pick a ball of radius $q-1$, so it includes no point in $[0,1]$?

Comment: [0,1] int Q *is* closed in Q but not in R.  However the Heine Borel Theorem does not apply in the metric space Q because Q is not complete, so 1)Yes $[0,1]\cap Q$ is closed and bounded in Q) 2) No it isn't compact in Q but 3) The theorem isn't true in Q

Comment: A metric space $(X,d)$ is compact iff it is *complete* and totally bounded.

Comment: "Q being closed means that Q contains all of its limit points. Is that true?"  Yes.  In the metric space Q does most certainly and uequivicly *does* contain all of its limit points.  "The problem with your argument is that Q∩[0,1] is not closed." In the metric space Q it most certainly is closed. "Isn't the complement of Q∩[0,1]=Q∖[0,1 open in QQ?" Absolutely! (but it absolutely is not open in R, of course.)

Comment: The OP *clearly* stated "in the metric space Q".  So the OP is absolutely *correct* in claiming the set is closed and bounded.  The mistake in the OP is *not* that the set isn't closed, but that the theorem doesn't apply to the metric space Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalence between compactness and "closed and totally bounded" is only true in *complete* metric spaces. Since $\Bbb Q$ is not complete, you need to require more than closure, you need to require completeness.

Namely, a metric space $(X,d)$ is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. You are absolutely right that $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is totally bounded, by the argument that you present. And you are right that it is closed in $\Bbb Q$.

But while in $\Bbb R$ being closed is enough (because a closed subset of a complete metric space is complete); in $\Bbb Q$ it is not enough to be closed in order to be compact.

Comment: Thank you so much, now everything makes perfect sense!! I suppose the generalised hein-borel theorem does require the metric space to be complete then, as the proof does involve cauchy sequence being convergent.